# Do I really need to write this "SerializationHelper"?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, serialization

I just wrote this **SerializationHelper** class, but I can't believe this is necessary!

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public static class SerializationHelper
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        var outStream = new StringWriter();
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        ser.Serialize(outStream, obj);
        return outStream.ToString();
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string serialized)
    {
        var inStream = new StringReader(serialized);
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(inStream);
    }
}
```

And it's used like this:

```
var serialized = SerializationHelper.Serialize(myObj);
```

and:

```
var myObj = SerializationHelper.Deserialize<MyType>(serialized)
```

Am I missing something in the .NET framework?  This is not rocket science!

Comment: I haven't seen anything in the .NET framework to supplant your generic Serialize implementation.

Comment: This is probably a case of features starting at -100 (to paraphrase http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/15/making-it-easier.aspx). The BCL designers must not have thought that creating objects from xml strings (and vice versa) merited all the work that goes into adding a feature to the API - *particularly* since it isn't rocket science!

Comment: Normally serialization is a function of T, rather than a generic serializer. This is because it's not always necessary to serialize everything from a class in order to restore it thus the class with the specific knowledge is the better informed place to do this activity.

Comment: @Jeff, great blog link... I'd not read that before, pleased I did now.

Comment: That's what [XMLIgnore] is for!  You can still use the generic serializer, if all you want to do is ignore some fields.

Comment: Yes, Stan, it's a question... I don't want to re-invent the wheel and if this already done in the framework, I would like to use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's useful if you are doing any real amount (>1) of serialization/deserialization within a project. This was the case for me one time, so I just put a similar class in a Utils library, along with other reusable functions.

Answer (score 1):

In actual fact, the bits where you call the .NET API are these:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
ser.Serialize(outStream, obj);

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
var obj = (T) ser.Deserialize(inStream);
```

The rest of the code is your personal specialisation. I don't think that two lines of code is too much for calling an API. You could always condense them, e.g.

```
(new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Serialize(outStream, obj);

var obj = (T) (new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(inStream);
```

Purely as an aside, I should point out that I regard storing XML data in string variables as a Code Smell. As soon as you take XML data out of its raw binary form (`XDocument`, `XmlDocument`, `XPathDocument` or any other type of DOM), you run up against encoding issues. What if a developer serialises an object to a string with encoding X, then writes the string to a disk file with encoding Y? Not very safe. Besides which, if encoding X is not UTF-16, how would you even represent the data in a .NET string?

Comment: You are missing a cast to T in your last line... otherwise I get an "object".  And you are leaving out of your "condensing" the fact that I have to mention the type name explicitly a lot, which my solution obviates

Comment: Joel, I agree, it's a lot of typing. You have to ask yourself, at what point does writing a utility method to save yourself typing become a waste of time? If your methods genuinely save you time and make your code more readable, then that's great, keep them. All I am saying is, the designers of the `XmlSerializer` API did not happen to agree with you.